# Meta Learning with pytorch DistributedDataParallel, the result changes when rank changes?

Tags: pytorch, distributed

I want to implement meta learning with pytorch DistributedDataParallel. However, there are two issues:

1. After setting `loss.backward(retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)`, an error occured, said `RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.` If only set `retain_graph=True`, it works fine.
2. When I set `retain_graph=True` and run the code, I found that the second order gradient changes with respect to the number of ranks, while the loss doesn't change. I found the key problem may come from the `get_update_network()`. However, I can work it out that how this happened and how to fix it.

e.g.

```
DataParallel

grad1 :  tensor(3.5100, device='cuda:0')
net2 :  tensor([[ -3.9810, -13.5981,  -4.1402, -36.6334]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
grad2 :  tensor(7.0200, device='cuda:0')
loss1 : -8.781850814819336, loss2 : -1550.81201171875

DistributedDataParallel

rank 1 

grad1 :  tensor(3.5100, device='cuda:0')
net2 :  tensor([[ -3.9810, -13.5981,  -4.1402, -36.6334]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
grad2 :  tensor(7.0200, device='cuda:0')
loss1 : -8.781850814819336, loss2 : -1550.81201171875

rank 2 

grad1 :  tensor(3.5100, device='cuda:0')
net2 :  tensor([[ -3.9810, -13.5981,  -4.1402, -36.6334]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
grad2 :  tensor(6.5200, device='cuda:0')
loss1 : -8.781851768493652, loss2 : -1550.81201171875

rank 4 

grad1 :  tensor(3.5100, device='cuda:0')
net2 :  tensor([[ -3.9810, -13.5981,  -4.1402, -36.6334]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
grad2 :  tensor(5.5200, device='cuda:0')
loss1 : -8.781850814819336, loss2 : -1550.81201171875
```

The demo code is followed:

```
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn.parallel import DistributedDataParallel
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset

torch.manual_seed(1234)


def put_theta(model, theta):
    def k_param_fn(tmp_model, name=None):
        if len(tmp_model._modules) != 0:
            for (k, v) in tmp_model._modules.items():
                if name is None:
                    k_param_fn(v, name=str(k))
                else:
                    k_param_fn(v, name=str(name + '.' + k))
        else:
            for (k, v) in tmp_model._parameters.items():
                if not isinstance(v, torch.Tensor):
                    continue
                tmp_model._parameters[k] = theta[str(name + '.' + k)]

    k_param_fn(model)
    return model


def get_updated_network(old, new, lr, load=False):
    updated_theta = {}
    state_dicts = old.state_dict()
    param_dicts = dict(old.named_parameters())
    # print(param_dicts['module.backbone.conv1.0.weight'].grad.sum(), '\n')
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(state_dicts.items()):
        if k in param_dicts.keys() and param_dicts[k].grad is not None:
            updated_theta[k] = param_dicts[k] - lr * param_dicts[k].grad
        else:
            updated_theta[k] = state_dicts[k]
    if load:
        new.load_state_dict(updated_theta)
    else:
        new = put_theta(new, updated_theta)
    return new


class Datax(Dataset):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        data = [0.01, 10, 0.4, 33]
        data = torch.tensor(data).view(4).float() + item
        # data = torch.randn((4,))
        return data

    def __len__(self):
        return 100


class Net2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net2, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(4, 1, bias=False),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x.mean()


def train(rank, world_size):
    if rank == -1:
        net = nn.DataParallel(Net2()).cuda()
        net2 = nn.DataParallel(Net2()).cuda()
        opt1 = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
        dataset = Datax()
        loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True, sampler=None)
    else:
        net = DistributedDataParallel(Net2().cuda(), device_ids=[rank], find_unused_parameters=True)
        net2 = DistributedDataParallel(Net2().cuda(), device_ids=[rank], find_unused_parameters=True)
        opt1 = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
        dataset = Datax()
        sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(dataset, rank=rank, shuffle=False)
        loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=8//world_size, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True, sampler=sampler)

    for i, data in enumerate(loader):
        data = data.cuda()
        l1 = net(data).mean()
        opt1.zero_grad()
        # when set the create_graph=True, error occurs in the second loop
        l1.backward(retain_graph=True)
        if rank <= 0:
            # first gradients and losses are all the same for all ranks
            print('grad1 : ', net.module.conv[0].weight.grad[0, 0])

        # net2 = net  # this line works fine, so the error comes from this line
        # However, all ranks outputs same architecture and same loss, but the grad is different.
        net2 = get_updated_network(net, net2, 1)
        if rank <= 0:
            for k, v in net2.named_parameters():
                print('net2 : ', v)

        l2 = net2(data).mean()
        l2.backward()
        if rank != -1:
            dist.all_reduce(l1), dist.all_reduce(l2)
            l1 = l1 / world_size
            l2 = l2 / world_size
        if rank <= 0:
            print('grad2 : ', net.module.conv[0].weight.grad[0, 0])
            print('loss1 : {}, loss2 : {}'.format(l1.item(), l2.item()))

        opt1.step()

        if i == 0:
            break


def dist_train(proc, ngpus_per_node, args):
    backend = 'nccl'
    url = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:23458'
    world_size = args
    dist.init_process_group(backend=backend, init_method=url, world_size=world_size, rank=proc)
    torch.cuda.set_device(proc)
    train(proc, world_size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train(-1, 4)
    for i in [1, 2, 4]:
        print('\n')
        ranks = i
        torch.manual_seed(1234)
        mp.spawn(dist_train, nprocs=ranks, args=(ranks, ranks))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the second issue. in the last warnning of [Pytorch DistributedDataParallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel), it says

> You should never try to change your model’s parameters after wrapping up your model with DistributedDataParallel. In other words, when wrapping up your model with DistributedDataParallel, the constructor of DistributedDataParallel will register the additional gradient reduction functions on all the parameters of the model itself at the time of construction. If you change the model’s parameters after the DistributedDataParallel construction, this is not supported and unexpected behaviors can happen, since some parameters’ gradient reduction functions might not get called.

Becasue I modified the parameters of one network, the gradients cannot be averaged automatically. So the second issue can be solved by average the gradient for distributed models on your own.

```
def average_gradients(model):
    size = float(dist.get_world_size())
    for param in model.parameters():
        dist.all_reduce(param.grad.data, op=dist.ReduceOp.SUM)
        param.grad.data /= size

loss.backward()
average_gradients(net)
```